# Yeast for dubbel

Tags: yeast, belgian, wyeast

I was planning on making 35L of 1.070 ish OG dubbel on Friday.  I don't have any yeast to hand and was wondering whether the smack packs of http://www.brewuk.co.uk/wyeast-activator-3787-trappist.html would be appropriate at, if so, what pitch rate would be best?  I use brewtoad for recipes and it's suggesting >300 bn cells are needed, which would make this pretty pricey yeast order.  Better to leave for another time and make a starter, or would under-pitching this be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When can you get the yeast? I would definitely not go for it if you're not going to be able to let it get started at all. If you can get the yeast a day or two in advance and get it partially started then you're more likely to avoid off flavors. Even if you have to cut it a little short. You might try buying a couple packs and giving those a short start.

However, let's be clear the best beer will come from waiting for a proper starter. Looking at the [BJCP style guide for the dubbel](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style18.php) doesn't look good. Under pitching you're likely to end up with more fruity flavors and less of many other characteristics, like body and malt, according to [this article at Science Brewer.](http://sciencebrewer.com/2012/03/02/pitching-rate-experiment-part-deux-results/)

Comment: As I feared :(.  I'll have to go have a look for other high ABV beers (looking to get the best use out of a conical that I want to leave alone for 6 weeks).

Comment: What about pitching the yeast 3 days after brewday - or is the risk of infection significantly increased this way?

Comment: I think that it's a question of how much and what kind of risk you want to take. Under pitch and you have a low risk of contamination, but a higher risk of mediocre beer. Waiting to pitch you have a higher risk of contamination.